# Changing table size, making pictures stretch/fit into them

Tags: html, css, html-table

[image: http://prntscr.com/3xkr34]

I'm trying to make the table become smaller and and also make the pictures stretch/fit properly into the table. No idea on how to start.

What do I do on the CSS? 
Any help will be much appreciated !

```
<table id="member" >
    <tr>

            <td><img src="1.jpg" ></td>
            <td><img src="2.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="3.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="4.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="5.jpg"></td>
            <td><img src="6.jpg"></td>




    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Let's see some HTML and any CSS that you already have :)

Comment: Using `height:` in `tables` `css` is useless. You'll need to use `div` with `display:table;` as css. and yeah let your code speak.

Comment: "No idea on how to start.

What do I do on the css?" as per my understanding StackOverflow is not the place to find tutorials… [google](http://www.google.com) would be a good place to start...

Comment: @misterManSam do you want the entire thing? or just that , cause it's just a table with pictures in it.

Comment: @VedantTerkar do you mean i need to add a <div> inside the table for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to control table size you can use width and height definitions like so:

```
member{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   }
```

when you can obviously exchange 'px' with 'em/vh/vw'...depends on your way of working.

Now, to make the image stretch what you need to do is:

```
member td{
   background: url(yourImage.jpg) no-repeat;
   }
```

Please notice that in this example 'td' refers to all 'td's' in your table. Choosing a specific cell its another issue which i'm sure if you search, you can find the answer to.

Comment: it's working, but my images are not centered. do you by any chance know how to fix it? it takes only the side of it etc

Comment: i think text-align: center will do the work :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to involve a table in this, it seems :)

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/2835F/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#images {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center images */
}
img {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Change the image width percentage based on how many images you want to display side by side. 33% would give you 3 across. Change the `#images` `max-width` to whatever maximum width you want.

You might also want a `min-width` on `#images` as well.

[More on box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: I'm doing academic coding, so have to follow the rules of having tables :(

Comment: Wow, tell them that they are being archaic! :)